# XUL/Firefox: create new browser window on addon load

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, add-on

I'm developing bootstrapped Firefox addon. In my `startup` function I am constructing new instance of object, that creates new Firefox window with the following code:

```
function createWindow (cb) {
    const appHiddenWindow = Services.appShell.applicationProvidedHiddenWindow
        , hidden = Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;

    // For definition of OpenBrowserWindow() see
    //   http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js
    // Prior to Firefox 20 "private" option is silently ignored
    let parent = appHiddenWindow ? hidden : RecentWindow.getMostRecentBrowserWindow()
      , window = parent.OpenBrowserWindow({ private: true });
    window.addEventListener("load", onWindowLoad);
    return window;

    function onWindowLoad (e) {
        window.removeEventListener("load", onWindowLoad);
        window.gBrowser.addEventListener("pageshow", onPageShow);
    }

    function onPageShow (e) {
        dump("onPageShow\n");
        try {
            cb(window);
        } catch (e) {}
    }
}
```

For some unknown for me reasons this code behaves differently in different circumstances:
on Firefox prior to 20 if it is being executed on app startup, `onPageShow` callback never fires. I assume this is because `gBrowser`'s `selectedBrowser`  just doesn't load homepage and stops after `about:blank` has loaded. Why does it load homepage in new window when I reactivate my extension manually (when Firefox is loaded already)?

Trouble appears when it yet loads homepage into `selectedBrowser` (in newer Fx versions): in this case it doesn't start loading URL, specified by me and instead continues to load my homepage.

So how can I determine if `gBrowser` is gonna load homepage or not? And why does it behave differently on App startup and on addon reactivation?

*PS: For the above code to work one must do these `import`s and use following fallback:*

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
try {
    Cu.import("resource:///modules/RecentWindow.jsm");
} catch (e) { // Firefox prior to v20
    var RecentWindow = {
        getMostRecentBrowserWindow: function ()
            Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser")
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm on Mac OS if it matters.

Comment: Why you don't follow the more conventional path of adding a listener to the window mediator?

Comment: In my addon I need my own (additional) window, that is opened by addon itself. This window will do some work in background.

In case of using window mediator I will need to open new window manually, have I understood you correct?

Comment: Do you want a hidden window (but then why fallback to a normal one?) or a window as soon as possible?

Comment: I need a new (ordinary, not hidden) window immediatly after my addon is activated. For this I use `OpenBrowserWindow` function that is defined in browser overlay of already existed window, but I supposed that on MacOS in some circumstances there might be no real window during activation of my addon. That is why I fallback to hiddenWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was wrong in some of my assumptions. I don't have to wait until `pageshow` event. After a long research I found this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=364304). According to it there is an observer notification `browser-delayed-startup-finished` that is enough to start doing things I had to do with `window`.